# Is it possible to display variables outside rules using GNU Make?

Tags: bash, make, gnu-make

Is it possible to display variables outside rules using GNU Make?

Consider the following Makefile:

```
x = foo bar baz

ifdef x
    @echo $(x)
endif
```

This results in `Makefile:4: *** commands commence before first target.  Stop.`

However, if I add a rule, it works:

```
x = foo bar baz

ifdef x
t:
    @echo $(x)
endif
```

Is it really necessary to add rules for outputting variables for debugging, etc.?

Bonus:

Why does the removal of `ifdef` result in `Makefile:3: *** missing separator.  Stop.`?

```
x = foo bar baz

@echo $(x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GNU make` has a feature for doing exactly that and it is  called `$(info ....)`.

You could place the following line outside of a `rule` and GNU make will execute it:

```
$(info variable x = $x))
```

And if you find yourself doing this sort of a task repeatedly, you can abstract it away in a `macro` and call it where ever needed:

```
make -f - <<\eof

dumpvar = $(info variable `$1' value is >>>$($1)<<<)

ssl_enable = NO
$(call dumpvar,ssl_enable)

.PHONY: all
all:;@:
eof
```

It will display the following on stout:

```
variable `ssl_enable' value is >>>NO<<<
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. In general, can `make` functions always be called outside rules, like `$(info …)`? Not just on the LHS of variable definitions? I like to think of `$(info …)` as `make`’s version of `echo`.

Comment: Yes , you can call the functions outside rules. In fact , the rule section is the shell script zone where make executes the shell utilities to build the target.

Comment: What feature of `bash` are you using for `<<\eof`? I have never seen the usage of "\" in that context. I see that by removing it, `bash` attempts all kinds of substitutions, which leads to errors.

Comment: The backslash turns off all kinds of substitutions and is like a single quoted heredoc.

Answer (score 3):

ehm, possible, but useless.

You must understand that a Makefile is not like a shell script. A Makefile specifies targets and what must be done to make those targets. If you keep that in mind, the execution of a spurious command in the Makefile becomes a conceptual problem. When is that command going to be executed? There is no target that would trigger that command.

You could:

```
MY_VAR := $(shell ls)

all:
    @echo MY_VAR IS $(MY_VAR)
```

Note that I assumed GNU `make`.  This will execute `ls` for you and puts the output in `MY_VAR`. But that is a hack that should be avoided.

You can also try a extra target

```
extra: 
     @echo $(x)
```

and add that as pre-req for all other targets.

As for the bonus: it is because the line `@echo $(x)` has no separator. At this point in the file, `make` would expect a target with a `:` and there is no `:` on that line. (there are other possibilities, like a new variable assignment etc. of course)

Comment: Thanks. I don’t really see why your first example provides any value w.r.t the question (e.g., debugging purposes)? The “separator” part of the error message confuses me, indeed `make` could also have complained about a missing `=` for a variable definition?